# Why is my Navigator not responding anything?

Tags: flutter, navigator

I don't know why I got so many downvotes... I'm new here. Sorry for any misunderstandings. Hopefully, someone can finally help me with my problem.

My Navigator to my Settings Screen won't work. I hope that you'll help me. Thanks a lot! Heres the code.

Here's the main dart

```
void main() => runApp(biminda());

class biminda extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          primaryColor: Color(0xFFad1457),
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => HomeScreeen(),
        '/setting': (context) => Settings(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

From my homeScreen

```
Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 30),
              child: SideButton(
                functionality: 'Settings',
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Settings(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

I updated the Container but nothing changed.

```
Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 30),
              child: SideButton(
                functionality: 'Settings',
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Settings(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Thank you so much! I hope this will be solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

u didnt declare you setting() page in the main,
 In you main in MaterialApp u delete home replace it by initialRoute like code bellow,

```
MaterialApp(

//......
    initialRoute: '/',
          routes: {
            '/': (context) => HomePage(),
            '/setting': (context) => SettingsPage(), );
```

Comment: Ok I implemented the code and it runs but the button doesn't react. I'm so sad

Comment: Try pushNamed instead of push

Comment: Now I'm getting an error: The argument type MaterialPageRoute cant be assigned to the parameter type String. I will try to fix it. Thank you so much!:)

Answer (score 0):

Please add more details about your problem, here's my suggestion based on your code:

In Settings screen you don't need to do

```dart
Navigator.pop(context, MaterialPageRoute....);
```

Just do a

```dart
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I implemented @GirlWhoCode's Code and it runs but the button won't do anything. I just want to switch to the Settings Screen, but nothing happens.